# Coding issue with drawing a line

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I'd like to draw a horizontal line as a break between the photo section and text section.

Here's my website:

http://violetoeuvre.com/

Here's the jsfiddle where it's working:

http://jsfiddle.net/GCxh9/

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(980,0);
        ctx.stroke();

</script>
```

I've put that in the head. Here is my html:

```
<!-- CONTENT____________________________________________-->

<div class="content_wrapper">

<!-- Photo __________________________________________-->

    <div class="home_photo">
    </div>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="980" height="100" style="border:0px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
<!-- About___________________________________________________-->

    <div class="home_text">
        <p>Emma Carmichael is a writer and editor based in Brooklyn, NY, although she hails from Brattleboro, VT. Emma graduated from Vassar College in 2010 with a degree in Urban Studies; ETC...
    </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

It's clearly doing something since there's extra space in between elements. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you just use an `<hr>` element?

Comment: I tried that, but it was a white box even though i specified black. It also had a weird border. See what I mean? http://jsfiddle.net/GCxh9/1/

Comment: [it just needs proper styling](http://jsfiddle.net/kJNan/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");` is returning Undefined object.

**Screen Shot**:

[image]

Keep this code anywhere after the line `<canvas id="myCanvas" width="980" height="100" style="border:0px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.moveTo(0,0);
        ctx.lineTo(980,0);
        ctx.stroke();

</script>
```

Better  keep the above script **before closing body tag** `</body>` of the webpage

Answer (score 0):

There are several points here.

1. You are setting height=100. That is causing the extra space
2. And in case you are using chrome, it adds its own styles. In this case, the below div 'home_text' has a `<p>` which chromes applies

   p {
       -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
       -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
       -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
       -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
   }

Better use reset.css or something similar on your website.

And using canvas to create a divider might not be the most optimal way. Why not just have `<div>` and set its `width`, `height` and `background-color: black;`

Comment: I see. this all seems pretty complex for a simple line. If I use the <hr> tag, why is it creating that weird border around the color?
http://jsfiddle.net/GCxh9/1/

Comment: @Claire the `<hr>` tag has some implicit styling. Since your boxes on the left are immediately adjacent, you could also just give the top box a solid bottom border.

Comment: my guess.. you do not need to set `height: 2px;` its just a seperator.. again different browsers have different natives styles for html elements.